# How do I get accented letters to actually work on bash?

Tags: bash, cygwin, non-ascii-characters

My bash installation on cygwin doesn't handle accented letters properly. I tried adding

```
set input-meta on    # to accept 8-bit characters
set output-meta on   # to show 8-bit characters
set convert-meta on  # to show it as character, not the octal representation
```

to my input rc, but this doesn't quite work yet. Indeed, if I type

```
$ echo ù
```

then before i press enter it is automatically changed to

```
$ echo \303
```

although the output is right, for I get

```
$ echo \303
ù
```

I get the same result for anyother accented letter. Usually though I use a non-italian keyboard, and I use `autohotkey` to substitute letters with an apostrophe after them with an accented letter. When this is the case, accented letters get substituted with a `\302`, and they print garbage depending on the letter: prints a `3y` for a `ù`, a `¢` for an `ò`, and nothing for everething else.

How do I get all this to make sense?

EDIT: my locale settings, cygwin version and terminal are the following

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64 ferdi-Asus 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39 i686 Cygwin
$ locale
LANG=it_IT.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="it_IT.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ tty
/dev/pty1
```

I'm invoking it simply clicking the Cygwin terminal link. It redirects to

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

The relevant part of the autohotkey script is the following

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
...
::avra'::avrà
::avro'::avrò
...
```

Comment: Which Cygwin version are you using, and with what terminal? What's your locale setting, i.e. what are the values of LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE and LANG? In any case, `convert-meta` needs to be off for non-ASCII characters to work properly.

Comment: I edited my post to show what you asked. Turning off convert-meta doesn't seem to change anything actually.

Comment: Non-ASCII letters work fine for me wihtout convert-meta, and they stop working if I switch it on, which is not surprising looking at its description: "If set to ‘on’, Readline will convert characters with the eighth bit set to an ASCII key sequence by stripping the eighth bit and prefixing an ESC character, converting them to a meta-prefixed key sequence. The default value is ‘on’."

Comment: Again: which terminal are you using? Also, how are you invoking it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you asking which version of the terminal i was using. I added it to the question, along with the invoking link.

Comment: Have you tested ak2's suggestion of turning convert-meta off? I have similar results to yours when it is on, and no problems when it is off. As for your autohotkey issues, perhaps you could provide the script?

Comment: Setting it off doesn't change anything. 

The script is very simple in structure but quite long. I added an abstract to my question.

Comment: I believe that the difference in behaviour between the ones inserted via autohotkey and via keyboard rises from a difference in encoding, but i believe that is secundary.

Comment: Just for the record, [here's an excellent synopsis of things you should know about Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Is there any piece of information I could add to the question to make it more easily answered? I can tell that some of you are disappointed by me not being explicative enough, so please tell me how I can help you help me.

Comment: Try ONE of the following: __(1)__ revert all your input rc changes, restart your terminal, confirm that `locale` yields `it_IT.UTF-8` and going to the `mintty` menu > Options > Text your locale is `it_IT` and your charset is `UTF-8`; backup your current `autohkey` script and use e.g. notepad++ to open your `autohotkey` script and convert to **UTF-8 without BOM** instead of ANSI. Try it out. If failed, __(2)__ restore the backed up `autohotkey`, then in the `mintty` menu change the charset to `CP1252 (ANSI codepage)` for locale `it_IT`, `export LC_ALL=it_IT.CP1252` and try again.

Comment: see here [answer from JdeBP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200255/bash-displays-international-characters-as-escape-sequences) fior details.
Adding comments on the same line in an inputrc line is not supported and disables the option or something.
so your inputrc changes didn't do what you thought they did.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get accented letters on bash via `Cygwin` using `Mintty 1.1.2` just do the following:

1. Go to the **menu** (if you don't see any menu, right click on your Terminal).
2. Click **Options...**.
3. Click **Text**.
4. Change the **Locale** to `C`.
5. Change the **Character set** to `ISO-8859-1 (Western European)`.

[image: Changing Locale and Character set in Mintty 1.1.2]

Then test it:

[image: Echoing accented letters in Mintty 1.1.2]

Comment: Thank you! This works when I use the regular italian layout, but not when I do insert accented letters via my autohotkey script. This should not be a big deal, since my main purpose is being able to write scripts using accents rather than issuing commands with accents directly in the shell.

I'll give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: I suggest using UTF-8 unless you have a specific reason to use ISO-8859-1. Of course that will affect how accented characters are stored.